# Using any-text with Node: error: require function can't be statically extracted

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, require, npm-start

I'm trying to implement text extraction for various filetypes in a Node/React project. I stumbled across the any-text library that's built in to Node.

To simplify the test process I got it to run from the command line with js. Now that I have this set of functions working I want to import the functions into another file. When I try to run the project with npm start I get:

```
Compiled with warnings.

./node_modules/pdf-parse/lib/pdf.js/v1.9.426/build/pdf.js
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

./node_modules/pdf-parse/lib/pdf.js/v1.10.100/build/pdf.js
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

./node_modules/pdf-parse/lib/pdf.js/v1.10.100/build/pdf.js
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

./node_modules/pdf-parse/lib/pdf.js/v1.10.100/build/pdf.js
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

./node_modules/pdf-parse/lib/pdf.js/v1.10.88/build/pdf.js
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
...(additional similar warnings)
```

I'm not sure how to address this, tweaking the version of things or throwing an ignore warnings in there or some other thing.

Here's the package.json in case that it has some useful information:

```
{
  "name": "topic_analysis",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "antd": "^4.16.10",
    "any-text": "^1.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "lda": "^0.2.0",
    "mammoth": "^1.4.17",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "pizzip": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-file-picker": "0.0.6",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-pdf": "5.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "read-text-file": "^1.1.0",
    "use-file-picker": "^1.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at the look of your package.json there is no module named
pdf-parse

maybe try to install it by

```
npm install pdf-parse
```